# State classification of Markov chains

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification, markov-chains

Consider the Markov chain on $S=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ with transition matrix

$$P=\begin{pmatrix}0&1/2&1/4&1/4&0&0\\1&0&0&0&0&0\\0&1/3&0&1/3&0&1/3\\0&0&0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&1&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

I want to determine which states are essential, recurrent or transient, and whether $S$ is irreducible. I then want to find the period of each of the states.

My attempt is as follows:

I tried drawing a state-space diagram, but this was very messy. From that I determined that there are two communicating classes, which are $\{1,2,3\}$ and $\{4,5,6\}$. Whether or not a state is essential is a class property, so $\{1,2,3\}$ is inessential, $\{4,5,6\}$ is essential. This is because we could go from $1\rightarrow 3\rightarrow 4$ and from $4$ we cannot return to $1$ (by looking at the state space diagram).

Hence $S$ is not irreducible as it consists of two communicating classes - in order for it to be irreducible it must be one single communicating class.I have absolutely no idea about recurrence or transience... Is there any way to be able to answer these question simply looking at the matrix or is the only way to draw a state space diagram?

Comment: From what you have done so far, you should be able to see $4,5,6$ are recurrent.  E.g. if you are in state $4$ there is a probability $1$ you will return to $4$ (in fact after exactly three steps, but that does not matter).  For $1,2,3$ you should look at the definition of transient and recurrent, but again it should be clear from what you have done so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I think a state-space diagram is, generally, a good way to go. There are other approaches, but for a problem like this -- one with just a few states -- I think this is by far the conceptually clearest way to go. (You said it was "very messy" -- I don't think I agree!)
2. I think you already know enough to answer the recurrence question. *Hint:* Would a random walk started at state 1 be *guaranteed* to eventually return to state 1? Why or why not?
3. If you want an approach that doesn't look at a state space diagram, you might consider this: if your matrix is $M$, then $M^{n}$ corresponds to the transition probabilities after taking $n$ steps. (This is the best part of representing a Markov chain by a transition matrix.) So, if your state space is aperiodic, then you can learn quite a lot about it by raising it to some large powers. If you can, I recommend raising your matrix to, say, the 100th power to see what you can see.

Comment: I guess that it is enough to raise to the power 6 here, and more generally to the power n, where n is the size of the matrix. Two states that can be connected by a path can be connected by a path of length n. Just remove the loops.

Comment: @coudy Interesting comment. I think the periodicity actually makes all this even a bit subtler (even than my original answer would have implied) because of periodicity, right? If you start at state 4, then in 6 steps will be at state 4 with certainty -- so you want to look at a few consecutive powers of the matrix to account for periodicity problems, most likely.

Comment: Yes, indeed, I was thinking about the aperiodic case. One should look at the sum $\sum_{0 \leq k\leq n} M^k$.

Comment: @coudy Hmm -- after thinking further, I don't agree with your "more generally to the pwoer $n$, where $n$ is the size of the matrix" claim. Consider a graph that is just two directed cycles -- one of length $5$, and one of length $6$, joined at some common vertex $o$ (so that a walk started at $o$ can enter either of the cycles). This chain is aperiodic, but the matrix $M^{11}$ will still be mostly zeroes because the aperiodicity won't have quite "mixed in" yet. It's certainly the case that there is some sufficiently large power you can usefully look at, but I don't think it's necessarily $n$.